# jPlayer MP3 stream not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, stream, jplayer

I've created an instance of a jPlayer object in Javascript, which loads an MP3 stream into the player, and then plays it automatically (hence the `.jPlayer('play');` on the end of the ready function.

This works fine in all browsers, except, typically, Internet Explorer. As much as I'd love to drop support for it, too many of the expected visitors use it, and so I need to come up with some solution.

Here is the code I'm using - is there any way I can modify it to allow it to function in IE, or do I need to add some IE only exception?

```
<!-- jQuery/jPlayer JS includes here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: "http://website.com:port/;stream/1"
                }).jPlayer('play');
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "mp3",
            solution: "flash,html",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//Custom player controls go here.
```

Comment: Just checking the basics - is your swf player inside the js folder as per the swfPath parameter?

Comment: Yes, it is. All the scripts are as should be located, and everything functions as you'd expect in all other browsers other than IE.

Comment: does it work in FF? What version of Flash do you have installed?

Comment: It was indeed due to the Flash version I had installed :O Thank you :D